# Video Projecting to a Receding Surface and Mapping from Viewers Perspective

Tags: rendering

I want to project a Blender animation, on to the floor, at the end of a dark hallway. Imagine a video projector mounted at the ceiling and pointed straight down. I want the animation to look correct to a viewer standing 8 feet away. Imagine an average person, perhaps 5’ 6"?

For example, if I animated a snake that lifted its head, and then crawled into the darkness, toward the viewer, I don’t want the snake to look like the distorted, flat, keystoned image you’d normally expect while standing off to the side of a projector screen. Rather, from the viewers perspective, the snake should appear as you’d expect an actual snake to appear.

To complicate matters, I want to take a photo, from the projectors perspective, of the floor, to use as a background in my animation, and when projected, exactly align with the existing floor. Obviously, the viewer would correctly see the floor as a flat, keystoned image. However, the snake, if composited correctly, would appear to sit on top of the floor, casting shadows, and blocking the view of the floor underneath and behind.

My question is about setting up and compositing the two different perspectives into a final render.  I imagine the first render would be of the snake animation that is then used to create a composite that includes the floor image.  That render would then be stretched and composited with the floor image and then baked into a floor surface for a final render.  Am I on the right track?

If such a tutorial exists, I would so appreciate a link. Otherwise, any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: One easy and accurate way is using *FSpy* in order to mimic the lens of the projector by creating a 3d camera on location: https://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy/blob/develop/projector_notes.md

Answer (score 0):

Here is an outline for a procedure, which might work to project an animation from the ceiling, which would appear correctly to a viewer standing 8 feet away. I appreciate any suggestions and corrections you may have. thanks.

A. First Render

1. Photograph Actual Scene of the Floor (flat lighting at Projector, Photograph from Viewer’s Perspective)
2. Model Scene of the Floor
3. Map & Bake Image of Actual Scene Onto the Virtual Scene
4. Create Model of Snake
5. Animate Snake Onto the Scene Model
6. Set up non-diffuse, shadow-casting light at the lens of virtual projector
7. Set up virtual Camera at Viewer’s Perspective
8. Render Preliminary Animation

B. Second Render

1. Project & Bake the Preliminary Animation Onto the Scene from Viewer’s Perspective
2. Set up virtual Camera at Lens of the Virtual Projector
3. Set up Soft Light at Lens of the Virtual Projector
   a. Turn off reflections (in material? In light?)
4. Render Final Animation